# ImageButton background not toggling programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I have two `buttons`, and they are coded programmatically (I do not have an `XML` file for it). I am trying to toggle the background `onClick`, but it is not toggling.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330089/programmatically-change-button-background-drawable-onclick) does not help me since it is deprecated, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330089/programmatically-change-button-background-drawable-onclick) did not work. I know how to do it with `XML`, but as I stated, I do not have one. How can I properly toggle the `ImageButton` background back and forth on click? When I click the `buttons`, the background changes, but it **stays that way** until I click it again. I want it to immediately toggle back to its original state.

Instantiation of `buttons` (Lots of code in between. Just showing relevant `button` code):

```
static final int leftFireButtonID = 3;
static final int rightFireButtonID = 4;

private boolean isLeftButtonClicked = false;
private boolean isRightButtonClicked = false;

leftFireButton = new ImageButton(this);
rightFireButton = new ImageButton(this);

leftFireButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_button);
rightFireButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_button);
```

Code for the listeners:

```
leftFireButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            soundPool.play(soundID,1.0f,0.5f,1,0,1.0f); //Pew pew gunfire

            if(view.getId() == leftFireButtonID) {
                isLeftButtonClicked = !isLeftButtonClicked;
                view.setBackgroundResource(isLeftButtonClicked ? R.drawable.red_button_pressed : R.drawable.red_button); //stays...needs to change back
            }
        }
    });
    rightFireButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            soundPool.play(soundID, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f); //Pew pew gunfire

            if(view.getId() == rightFireButtonID) {
                isRightButtonClicked = !isRightButtonClicked;
                view.setBackgroundResource(isRightButtonClicked ? R.drawable.red_button_pressed : R.drawable.red_button); //stays....needs to change back
            }
        }
    });
```

This was so easy with `XML` selectors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to do that with an `OnTouchListener` instead. An `OnClickListener` only fires after an `ACTION_UP` event.

Comment: I literally JUST did that just now before coming back to check my notification. Lol. Glad I got it figured out. Thank you for the comment though!

Answer (score 0):

Got myself in a hurry. Didn't do it properly. Set up an `onTouchListener` to get `ACTION.DOWN` and `ACTION.UP`. :-)

```
leftFireButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                leftFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button_pressed);
                soundPool.play(soundID,1.0f,0.5f,1,0,1.0f); //pew pew gunfire
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                leftFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
rightFireButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                rightFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button_pressed);
                soundPool.play(soundID,1.0f,0.5f,1,0,1.0f); //pew pew gunfire
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                rightFireButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```